# Azure Devops Repository with Terraform - already exists

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform

I'm terraforming Azure Devops resources (project + repo + pipeline). Here's my config:

```
resource "azuredevops_project" "project" {
  name               = var.app_base_name
  description        = "${var.app_base_name} project"
  visibility         = "private"
  version_control    = "Git"
  work_item_template = "Agile"
}

resource "azuredevops_git_repository" "repository" {
  project_id = azuredevops_project.project.id
  name       = var.app_base_name

  initialization {
    init_type = "Uninitialized"
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      initialization
    ]
  }
}

resource "azuredevops_build_definition" "build" {
  depends_on = [azuredevops_resource_authorization.subscription_auth]
  project_id = azuredevops_project.project.id
  name       = var.app_base_name

  ci_trigger {
    use_yaml = true
  }

  repository {
    repo_type   = "TfsGit"
    repo_id     = azuredevops_git_repository.repository.id
    branch_name = "master"
    yml_path    = "azure-pipelines.yml"
  }

  variable_groups = [
    azuredevops_variable_group.vars.id
  ]
}
```

So as you can see there are three connected resources to be set up by Terraform. The thing is that Azure Devops would not allow to create allegedly second repository with the same name. It seems that Azure Devops creates repo when creating a project but how terraform configs should be changed in order to not have this error?

```
Error creating repository in Azure DevOps: TF400948: A Git repository with the name XXX already exists.
```

Comment: Yes, DevOps create a repo when a project been created. And the name of them is same. So could you don't create same name repo in your terraform?

Comment: Yes, but then I will end up with two repos created by terraform - one created by azuredevops_project (with the same name), the other one created with azuredevops_git_repository (with changed name). I don't need dummy repos created ;)

Comment: @Murakami were you abel to find a solution/workaround? I'd relally like to avoid creating a second repository if one already exists.